# visual studio not detect 3d printers on network

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to detect my 3d printers on the network but for some reason it is only returning the 2d printers, whits is a bit strange because the 3d printers are connected on the network, and detectable from the native software.  Any ideas on how to display all network printers ?

```
using System;
using System.Printing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace PrintQueuesExample
{
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    PrintQueueCollection _Printers;

    public Window1()
    {
      _Printers = new PrintServer().GetPrintQueues(new[] { 
        EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections});

      foreach (var queue in _Printers)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Name);
        var capabilities = queue.GetPrintCapabilities();
        foreach (var size in capabilities.PageMediaSizeCapability)
        { Console.WriteLine(size.ToString()); }
        Console.WriteLine();
      }

      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public PrintQueueCollection Printers
    { get { return _Printers; } }

    private void PrintTestPageClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var queue = _PrinterList.SelectedItem as PrintQueue;
      if (queue == null)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a printer.");
        return;
      }

      var size = _SizeList.SelectedItem as PageMediaSize;
      if (size == null)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a page size.");
        return;
      }

      queue.UserPrintTicket.PageMediaSize = size;
      queue.UserPrintTicket.PageOrientation = _PortraitRadio.IsChecked == true ? 
        PageOrientation.Portrait : PageOrientation.Landscape;

      var canvas = (Canvas)Resources["MyPrintingExample"];
      canvas.Measure(new Size(size.Width.Value, size.Height.Value));
      canvas.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, canvas.DesiredSize.Width, 
          canvas.DesiredSize.Height));

      var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
      writer.Write(canvas);
    }

  }

  public class PrintQueueToPageSizesConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return value == null ? null :
        ((PrintQueue)value).GetPrintCapabilities().PageMediaSizeCapability;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }
}
```

Comment: and do 3d printers *normally* show in the printer list dialog? I would *imagine* that is reserved for traditional printers... I wouldn't know, though, not having a 3d printer. If you go into notepad to print: would it appear?

Comment: don't think 3D printer is identified like a *priner* itself. It should be *a device*, like a coin validator, or some usb lamp

Comment: Windows print drivers currently don't have a 3rd dimension.  so, it's unlikely they'd show up in *any* printer list in Windows.  If they *do* show up in the list of printers in the control panel, then should should up in the list of printers in a C# application.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt a 3D printer would appear in the **Printers** section of the **Windows Control-Panel** and therefore be seen as a printer. I think the name "3D Printer" is probably confusing, it isn't really a "printer" in the normal sense as Windows see it.

Most printers just know about rows / columns (to hugely over simplify things) so manufacturers can use a generic printer driver as a base. 3D printers are much more advanced / specialised and I am guessing that you will need an SDK that will output instructions that the 3D printer will understand.

You will probably be able to obtain an SDK from the manufacturer of the printer.